# new.instancemethod convert to python 3.3 in overloading script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to start out by saying I'm aware `new.instancemethod` doesn't exist in python 3 and overloading functions doesn't technically either.

However, I am looking at an old python package which uses `new.instancemethod` in a script that effectively allows for `overloaded functions`.

The specific package can be found from [this site](http://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/overload/overloading.py) although I've included what I believe is the relevant section below.

I am using python 3 so I need to convert it into a usable script for python 3. I've used the 2to3 tool and reviewed most of the changes already. However, I am stuck on the below which I can't figure out what to replace `new.instancemethod` with.

```
class overloaded:
    ...

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return new.instancemethod(self, obj)
```

Class overloaded is used in front of `__init__` as a decorator which is posing no problems, but it is a problem when it is used in front of a method because `obj` is no longer `None`.

The reason I need this, is because a) it is useful and b) because I am currently translating the out-of-date IbPy package from 2.56 to 3.x. The IbPy package is basically the Java API of Interactive Brokers translated into Python.

The main method that @overloaded is placed in front of can be found below:

```
@overloaded
@synchronized(mlock)
def eConnect(self, host, port, clientId):
    host = self.checkConnected(host)
    if host is None:
        return
    try:
        socket = Socket(host, port)
        self.eConnect(socket, clientId)
    except Exception as e:
        self.eDisconnect()
        self.connectionError()
```

Note that @synchronize is just a decorator that forces synchronization of multiple functions. The code is short and can be found [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Synchronization), although I don't believe it is relevant for my issue.

So after that long explanation, how would I get `return new.instancemethod(self, obj)` to look more python 3? I can't seem to wrap my head around what is happening despite reading about it for all of last night and this morning. I've tried many things already, and I think I just lack the understanding in python of how to handle this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`types.MethodType` should be used instead of new.instancemethod

or you can get instancemethod from any class:

```
instancemethod = type(Anyclass.method)
```

where method is any class method

[Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

Comment: funny I used that earlier but must have switched the arguments because it didn't work that time. Anyways it works. Thanks!